# How to make TwinCat works with docker

Tags: asp.net, docker, iis, plc, twincat

I have a Asp.net project need to communicate with PLC by twincat. It works well on Windows. However, to be easier for remote deployment we run into docker. The twincat doesn't work anymore because our host address changed to linux docker container. What's the easiest way to solve this problem or we are also consider to use IIS instead of docker, but version control becomes to a problem.

Comment: Hosting on IIS is not a bad thing. If you want to use Docker and no other way can be found, you can always develop and deploy a man-in-the-middle proxy app on your Docker host machine, which takes care of messages your web app sends and pass on to TwinCat PLC.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.